# Raw access to collection models,

Tags: backbone.js

Please look at this code:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#container',

    render: function() {
        var html = '';
/*        _.each(this.collection.models,function(model,index,list) {
            var item_html = 'FirstName: ' + model.get('firstName');
            html += item_html + '<br />';
        });*/
        html = this.collection.models.model.get('firstName');
        $(this.el).html(html);
    }
});
```

This code: "this.collection.models" gives access to model.get('firstName') when used in the _.each loop (commented out).
But when I try to access model.get trough the same code "this.collection.models" but outside of the loop it won't work.
My question is how to access to the 'firstName' attribute of object from model associated to that view, with raw(?) access, outside of the loop ? I know this would not iterate but I just want to learn how to get access to first instance "firstName".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the _.each loop, the 'model' parameter is passed to the callback function you've specified. Outside of the loop, you don't have the same structure. There are several ways to access a model within a collection, but it depends on which one you want access to. You could, if you wanted, access the first one in the models array by using an index:

```
this.collection.models[0].get('firstName');
```

but there are other methods provided to you to do this such as get which takes an id:

```
this.collection.get(123);
```

or at, which takes an index:

```
this.collection.at(0);
```

so it really depends on which one you want to get at.

Comment: Outstanding answer. There is so many way to do so many things, thanks for showing several ways.